# Entire function $f(z)$ that satisfies a given limit.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, entire-functions

I am given an entire function $f$ satisfies the limit
$$ \lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{f(z)^2}{z^3} = 0 . $$
I'm asked to determine the most general form of $f$.

I've thought of the following ways;

1. We know $f(z)^2$ is a polynomial of degree at most 2, thus; $f(z)^2 = \alpha + \beta z + \gamma z^2$. The most general form of $f$ is therefore
   $$
   f(z) = \pm \sqrt{\alpha + \beta z + \gamma z^2}.
   $$
2. We know $$ \lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{f(z)^2}{z^3} = 0 \implies \lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z^{3/2}} = 0. $$ However, Liouville's generalized theorem only states that $f(z)$ is a polynomial of at most $q$ if it is a non-negative integer and the limit $f(z) / z^q$ exits. Therefore I figure this yields no result.

I applied method 1 to a similar question where $f$ satisfies
$$ \lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{f(z)^2}{z} = 1\,,$$
concluding that $f(z) = \pm \sqrt{\alpha + z}$.

Can I do better than this?

Comment: Who said $f$ is a polynomial? $f(z) = \sin(z)$ also satisfies the limit.

Comment: @orlp Liouville's theorem if I'm correct.

Comment: Considering my counterexample of $f(z) = \sin(z)$ that cannot be right.

Comment: True, I did not see your edit on time :)
However, is it even possible to find a generalized form of $f$ in this case?
For the 'similar question'; Loiouville's theorm does apply, I figure.

Comment: @orlp - $f(z) = \sin z$ does not sautidfy the limit condition since $z$ may be complex.

Comment: @HansEngler I misunderstood what $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}$ means for complex $z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z\rightarrow \infty$ (as a complex variable), then $f(z)=a+bz$ is the only possibility. Genuine square-roots are not entire functions.

Answer (score 1):

If the limit condition in the assumption holds, then there exists $C > 0$ such that $|f(z)|^2 \le C |z|^3$ for all $|z| \ge 1$ and therefore (perhaps with a larger $C$) $|f(z)|^2 \le C(1 + |z|^3)$ for all $z$. Thus $|f(z| \le C(1 + |z|)^{3/2}$ for all $z$, for some $C$. Now apply Liouville's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Liouville's generalized theorem holds for any positive power, not just integer powers. So if $f$ is entire and $|f(z)| \le C|z|^p $ for large $|z|,$ then $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $\lfloor p\rfloor.$ In the problem at hand we have $|f(z)| \le C|z|^{3/2} $ for large $|z|.$ Therefore $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $1.$

Comment: Good to know as well! Thanks